# Excel VBA Matching against all cells in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel, match, matching

This table is made by pulling a variable number of columns from several workbooks into one. I keep track of the column index for "Key1" and "Key2" with integers "i1" and "i2", respectively.

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+
|  Thisjust   | Indexcode | Specialcode |   Key1    | Indexcode |  Some  | Specialcode |   Key2    | MATCH |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+
| isanexample |       101 |       27223 | 101_27223 |       101 | Values |        1112 | 101_1112  |       |
| isanexample |       102 |       27224 | 102_27224 |       102 | Values |        1113 | 102_1113  |       |
| isanexample |       103 |       27225 | 103_27225 |       103 | Values |        1114 | 103_1114  |       |
| isanexample |       104 |       27226 | 104_27226 |       104 | Values |        1115 | 104_1115  |       |
| isanexample |       108 |       11130 | 108_11130 |       105 | Values |        1116 | 105_1116  | Yes   |
| isanexample |       106 |       27228 | 106_27228 |       106 | Values |        1117 | 106_1117  |       |
| isanexample |       107 |       27229 | 107_27229 |       107 | Values |        1118 | 107_1118  |       |
| isanexample |       110 |       27227 | 110_27227 |       108 | Values |       11130 | 108_11130 | Yes   |
| isanexample |       109 |       37345 | 109_37345 |       109 | Values |        1112 | 109_1112  |       |
| isanexample |       105 |       37346 | 105_37346 |       110 | Values |        1113 | 110_1113  |       |
| isanexample |       111 |       37347 | 111_37347 |       111 | Values |        1114 | 111_1114  |       |
| isanexample |       112 |       37348 | 112_37348 |       112 | Values |        1115 | 112_1115  |       |
| isanexample |       113 |       37349 | 113_37349 |       113 | Values |        1116 | 113_1116  |       |
| isanexample |       114 |       37350 | 114_37350 |       114 | Values |        1117 | 114_1117  |       |
| isanexample |       115 |       37351 | 115_37351 |       115 | Values |        1118 | 115_1118  |       |
| isanexample |       116 |       11138 | 116_11138 |       116 | Values |       11138 | 116_11138 | Yes   |
| isanexample |       117 |       11139 | 117_11139 |       117 | Values |       11139 | 117_11139 | Yes   |
| isanexample |       118 |       11140 | 118_11140 |       118 | Values |       11140 | 118_11140 | Yes   |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

I am checking if

EITHER key1 in a particular row matches one of the key2 cells

OR if key2 in a particular row matches one of the key1 cells

I used this formula to accomplish that

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(MATCH(H2,$D$2:$D$19,0)),ISNA(MATCH(D2,$H$2:$H$19,0))),"","Yes")
```

Knowing that this whole table could have a wildly different number of columns, and the order of columns is also variable:

How do I do my match function in VBA? The MATCH column will always be at the end.

Comment: So, there will always be `key1` and `key2` columns but you don't know their position, is that correct?

Comment: Is this formatted as a table? If so, you could do something like this `=IF(AND(ISNA(MATCH([Key1],[Key2],0)),ISNA(MATCH([Key2],[Key1],0))),"","Yes")`.

Comment: It's not yet formatted as a table, I don't know how to do that in VBA. That sounds like it might be the simplest solution.
Ahmed has the right idea, that I will always have the columns, but not the position. I do track the column number with an integer.

Comment: ListObjects: see [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel). Once you have a `ListObject`, you can reference the `ListColumn` by its header, bypassing the need to track its position with an integer.

Comment: BigBen's method worked perfectly! `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$19"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with creating a Table (`ListObject`) from your data, your MATCH column formula will be `=IF(AND(ISNA(MATCH([Key1],[Key2],0)),ISNA(MATCH([Key2],[Key1],0))),"","Yes")`.

This references the `Key1` and `Key2` columns based on their headers, eliminating the problem of a changing number and/or order of columns.